# Android HTTP POST params send but server doesn't get it

Tags: java, android, rest, http-post, httpclient

**Calling of API**

```
    HttpUriRequest httpRequest = null;
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    String postParameters = "email=" + email + "&name=" + name;

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8");
    request.setEntity(stringEntity);

    httpRequest = request;

    response = client.execute(httpRequest);
```

I am not getting post params at server side. Get param works. The same API works from other REST clients but not from android.

Comment: the permission for internet is set?

Comment: Could you tell me what do you use in server side app?

Comment: @StefanBeike : yes. get http method works.

Comment: do you try to call a local server?

Comment: Using Zend Framework2. this is how i get the post param. $this->getRequest()->getPost('realName')

Comment: @StefanBeike : No I am calling production APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable httpRequest is useless. Is variable postParameters a String?

Here example of sending post to upload image with some params.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.url));

try {
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    builder.addPart("picture", new FileBody(mSharedImagePath, ContentType.create("image/jpeg")));

    // Adding params
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "utf-8 encoded text");
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "another utf-8 encoded text");

    for (NameValuePair param : params) {
        builder.addTextBody(param.getName(), param.getValue(), ContentType.create("text/plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    }

    builder.setCharset(MIME.UTF8_CHARSET);
    httppost.setEntity(builder.build());

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    resEntity.getContentLength();
    //......

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Logger.getInstance().log(e);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Logger.getInstance().log(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.getInstance().log(e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.getInstance().log(e);
}
```

---

In your code it can be like this

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","my email"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","my name"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: You can remove variable httpRequest at all, and put variable request to client.execute method.
Adding params you can do the same as in my example

Comment: what difference it would make?

Comment: Difference is that you wouldn't create excess variable. This is just about code style, not about sending post request.

Comment: but the thing is i am using the httpRequest for different methods like "get","post","delete","put". I am using same httpRequest for everything. And in particular block i am create httpPost, httpGet and assigning it to httpRequest and destroying it.

Comment: In your code it wasn't mentioned, so it's looks like useless. What about your main question, my example helped?

Comment: that's what i asking. rather than giving totally different code. can you suggest changes in my code if there is any ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47757/discussion-between-cooperok-and-bsthakrar)

Comment: see. I updated my question with the code that i want to pass as post params